# sns.regplot shows a shaded area for the regression which does not make sense

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Given:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [1,2,3]})
ax = sns.regplot(x="a", y="b", data=f)
```

I get this graph which is confusing as the points are perfectly lined up. Why would there be the shaded area? I guess I dont understand what the shading means exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the confidence interval of your regression estimates, you can see under ci option of `sns.regplot`:

> ci int in [0, 100] or None, optional Size of the confidence interval
>   for the regression estimate. This will be drawn using translucent
>   bands around the regression line. The confidence interval is estimated
>   using a bootstrap; for large datasets, it may be advisable to avoid
>   that computation by setting this parameter to None.

In your example, the data is bootstrapped, and regression fitted, predictions obtained over 1000x, so for each data point you can have a 95% ci. Bootstrap is with replacement, so you can get say [1,1,2] and [1,1,2] and so on, hence the error your see. In general when you have smaller number of samples the error can be larger

You can turn this off by:

```
ax = sns.regplot(x="a", y="b", data=f,ci=None)
```